# ASP.NET MVC 3 URL redirect without URLRewrite

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting

I have ASP.NET MVC 3 project in me IIS. I need to implement 301 redirect and i have sample like this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.ua$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/robots.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.ua/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Is there a way to implement such thing in MVC 3 without adding URLRewrite module to IIS?

Ok, so I installed URLRewrite and here is my web.config

```
<rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example.com$" />
                        <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/robots.*" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example.com/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
```

I need this thing to redirect from example.com to www.example.com. But now it doesn't redirect.

Comment: When and where do you need to redirect?

Comment: Actually, its my SEO-guy told me to add that "301 redirect" script and I'm really don't know what to do with his advice.

Comment: Easiest way to install module as you said and import rules: http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/importing-apache-modrewrite-rules Or, you always can create simple HttpModule, which will do redirection

Comment: I am not allowed to install modules to IIS, so could you tell me more about how to create that simple HttpModule?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using `MVC 3` there are three redirect methods that you can use in your controller redirect permanently (301):

- RedirectToRoutePermanent
- RedirectPermanent
- RedirectToActionPermanent

Here's an example:

```
Response.RedirectPermanent("http://www.google.com");
```

or for returning an ActionResult type from a controller:

```
return RedirectPermanent("http://www.google.com");
```

Comment: I'm replacing previous coder on this project and I'm newby in this MVC world. Your advice is good but I don't know where exactly I need to write those responses and especially with hat rewrite conditions I mentioned above.

Comment: Another one: http://www.bugdebugzone.com/2013/10/difference-between-responseredirect-and_20.html